# How to delete expired Facebook access tokens from database and keep only active?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a database in which i have 60 Facebook access tokens of users. About 30 of them are expired but i don't know which of them are expired. I want to delete the expired tokens from database and want to keep only the active tokens in database.
So i want a script which access the database and refresh all tokens to keep active tokens only in database and delete expired tokens.

This the image of database having user name, id number, access token.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKyU5.png

Comment: Whether or not a token is expired, you’ll find out aynyway the next time you make an API call using it – and since you probably want to get a fresh token at that point anyway, I don’t see much sense in explicitly checking for expired tokens and deleting them. Anyway, you can [debug access tokens via API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug) – but if you try to do that for 60 tokens in one go, you’re likely to run into a script timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest NOT storing access tokens in a database, rather in the session.. Then the session garbage collection will take care of them.

Comment: can't you help me here??